# MS Graph API Sharepoint GetDriveItem

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Graph API is driving me nuts. I am trying and reading for hours and still can't get it to work.

I work with Sharepoint which contains a subsite, where there is DocumentLibrary with serveral folders.

I search the API: (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query)

```
                   "hits": [
                        {
                            "hitId": "01XPDM72T7SCIOG6BP4BAYQ5QI5RFFAESK",
                            "rank": 1,
                            "summary": "<c0>test</c0><ddd/><c0>test</c0><ddd/>",
                            "resource": {
                                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
                                "size": 4,
                                "id": "3",
                                "createdDateTime": "2021-01-08T12:11:12Z",
                                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-01-08T12:11:12Z",
                                "name": "test.txt",
                                "webUrl": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SubSite/Gedeelde documenten/test.txt",
                                "fileSystemInfo": {
                                    "createdDateTime": "2021-01-08T12:11:12Z",
                                    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-01-08T12:11:12Z"
                                },
                                "lastModifiedBy": {
                                    "user": {
                                        "displayName": "Admin"
                                    }
                                },
                                "parentReference": {
                                    "driveId": "2",
                                    "siteId": "1",
                                    "sharepointIds": {
                                        "listId": "[snip]",
                                        "listItemUniqueId": "[snip]"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

So far so good. I find a driveItem, and now want to get the contents.

in the parentReference I see driveId, siteId and id in the resource.
to my knowledge:

```
{site-id} = 1;
{drive-id} = 2;
{item-id} = 3;
```

If I look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get I can use several functions.

I start with `/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}` and `/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}`

Response:
`"error": { "code": "itemNotFound", "message": "The resource could not be found.",`

`/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveItem`

Response:

`"error": { "code": "itemNotFound", "message": "The specified list was not found",`

Nothing works.
Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Please firstly get the valid site id using this endpoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=yoursitename`, the site id shouldn't be a int value, it will like this:

[image]

Then access the specific libray like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/TenantName.sharepoint.com,91a47a59-db5e-4d17-a689-479ee8905533,274459c9-4c96-42bf-9b96-838ffa387aaa/lists/doc2/items/10/driveItem
```

The library is named "doc2" and get the item id "10":

[image]

[image]

Comment: Indeed I stripped the siteId.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. List can't be found (itemNotFound).
The name is "Gedeelde documenten". template documentLibrary.
But nothing works :(

Comment: When using the Graph API Explorer I get output:


/sites/[siteId]/lists/e2263f16-8382-4097-a1ed-70bac7ba752c/items/160

I now get contents of a file. When using the Graph API in PHP I get: 

  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified list was not found",

I am stuck

Comment: So you can get the valid content using Graph Explorer now, that means the request is valid. If you want to call in PHP, you can use this sdk: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php

Answer (score 0):

> So far so good. I find a driveItem, and now want to get the contents.

To download the file from SharePoint:

```
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http